# Controle de Sessão PHP / jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou criando um sistema onde tenho grupos de usuários com permissões específicas. Preciso fazer um controle de sessão no momento do login, armazenando as permissões do usuário em variáveis de sessão para que fiquem disponíveis em todas páginas, para assim verificar em quais recursos e/ou páginas o usuário tem permissão de acesso.
Eu já tive contato com as variáveis de sessão do PHP, porém, fazendo dessa forma eu teria que incluir um trecho de código PHP nas páginas HTML. Existe uma forma de fazer isso deixando o PHP totalmente separado do HTML? 
Vi um plugin chamado jquerysession.js para lidar com isso, alguém já utilizou e sabe informar se é uma boa opção? Caso sim, teria um exemplo de uso? 
Grato desde já!

Comment: Já ouviu falar em  MVC? Model  View Controller, dessa forma vc consegue o codigo server-side e cliente-side, no  php temos o > laravel, zend framework

Comment: Já ouvi falar em laravel, mas nunca pesquisei sobre. Comecei a pouco tempo em web. Vou dar uma olhada!

Comment: Acho que sua pergunta não se encaixa bem na proposta do site (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Sugiro que pesquise melhor sobre as alternativas em termos de architetura de solução de software para que sua pergunta seja mais específica.